# How to read "14-OCT-2016" or "%dd-%mon-%YYYY" with zoo? r / zoo/ xts

Tags: r, date, time-series, xts, zoo

title is self explanatory. i have a `df` with the first column as  `"14-OCT-2016"` running all the way down. I need to read this `df` as `.xts`

i looked at:

```
df$NAV.Date <- as.Date(df$NAV.Date, "%Y %b %d" )  # this replaces all values with NA

df$NAV.Date <- strftime(test$NAV.Date, format="%Y %b %d" )
```

for the last one i get :

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sys-locale problem (most likely). Here is how to solve it:

```
test<-"14-OCT-2016"
lct<-Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","C") #moves you to the right locale
date<-as.Date(test, "%d-%b-%Y")
print(date)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",lct) #moves you back again
```

Hope that helps :D

For the second problem, you have to use `lubridate` instead

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time("12-OCT-2015", tz="UTC", c("dbY", "dby"), locale = "C")
parse_date_time("12-OCT-15", tz="UTC", c("dbY", "dby"), locale = "C")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem is partially solved. I now seem to have a bad entry. I can only assume there are more ( i have 5m rows) the data sets it's entered as "16-Feb-15" instead of "16-FEB-2015". for that particular row i get "0015-02-16" when using your code. is it possible to adjust to account for this?

Comment: @AlexBădoi see updated answer. That could handles both. You need to adjust the timezone argument `tz`accordingly. In the example I set it to "UTC"

Answer (score 0):

The one-line solution is the following one, with help of the package `anytime`:

```
test <- "14-OCT-2016"
date <- anytime::anydate(test)
#[1] "2016-10-14"
```

The second problem can be solved with `lubridate`:

```
test2 <- "16-Feb-15"
date2 <- lubridate::dmy(test2)
#[1] "2015-02-16"
```

Comment: everything works good. It seems however that i have a band entry in one of the data sets it's entered as  "16-Feb-15" instead of "16-FEB-2015" could 'anytime' cover this too? at the moment this cell is left as blank